# A continuous map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is proper if and only if

Tags: general-topology

A map $f : X \to Y$ is proper when for $C \subset Y$ compact , $f^{-1}(C) \subset X$ is compact too. I'm asked to prove

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is proper if and only if

$$\lim_{x \to + \infty \\ or \ x \to - \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$$

My attempt: Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact. Then due to the limit condition, $f^{-1}(C)$ is contained in an open $D \subset \mathbb{R}$

But couldn't move any further (Basically I'm trying to prove that the closed $f^{-1}(C)$ is contained in a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$)

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $$\lim_{x \to + \infty \\ or \ x \to - \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$$

Let $C$ be a  is compact, it is closed, thus $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed, it is enough to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is bounded. Suppose it is not bounded, since $C$ is compact, there exists $A$ such that for every $x\in C, |x|\leq A$. Since we suppose $f^{-1}(C)$ is not bounded, there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $|x_n|>n$ and $f(x_n)\in C$, we can extract a sequence $x_{n_p}$ from $x_n$ converges towards $-\infty$ or $+\infty$, if $lim x_{n_p}=-\infty$, we have $f(x_{n_p})\in C$ implies that $|f(x_{n_p})|<A$. Contradicition. Same argument if $lim x_{n_p}=+\infty$.

On the other hand, suppose that $f$ is proper and there exists $A>0$ such that for every integer $n$, there exists $x_n>n$ such that $|f(x_n)|<A$, we deduce that $f^{-1}([-A,A])$ is not bounded, contradiction.